# Is it possible to use a custom font for form entries?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-forms

I'm working on a spreadsheet listing data entered through a Google Form. The entries should be automatically be formatted upon submission, but there are limitations.

I am already using Conditional Formatting to automatically modify what I can - namely colors. However, CF doesn't allow you to change the font, font size, text-align or cell borders.

[image: Formatted Sheet]

Here's what my sheet currently looks like - the first 3 entries have been manually formatted, while the fourth one is what a response looks like as soon as it has been submitted.

I would like new responses to automatically use a font different from Arial 10, as well as align center and use a predefined border if specified.

Comment: Doubt this is possible without using Google Apps Script.

Comment: you shouldn't do this directly on submitted data. if you would query it out under alt sheet you could pre-set your desired format which will be not altered by new submissions